# Piper pipeline Cloud Foundry deployment is failing with the latest ppiper/cf-cli docker image

Tags: sap-project-piper, sap-btp-sdk-ios

We are working on SAP BTP Cloud Foundry environment. For CI/CD pipeline, we are using the latest available version of "ppiper/jenkins-master"(in docker hub) for hosting jenkins and the piper pipeline runs in conjunction with this instance of Jenkins.

In the 'release stage' of the aforesaid piper pipeline, we are using the latest docker image of "ppiper/cf-cli" for deployment to BTP Cloud Foundry environment.

However, we are encountering the below issue with the latest version of "ppiper/cf-cli" docker image while triggering the release stage in the piper pipeline.
[image]

Owing to the above stated issue, piper pipeline deployment to Cloud Foundry with latest ppiper/cf-cli image errors out.

As a workaround for the above issue, currently we have switched back to the previous version (v14) of the image ppiper/cf-cli i.e. ppiper/cf-cli:v14 and with this, deployment to Cloud Foundry environment is getting successful.

We are afraid this might be piper pipeline compatibility issue with the latest image of ppiper/cf-cli for deployment. We are not sure at this point of time whether it is only our issue or a global issue for the latest version of ppiper/cf-cli.
Hence, in this regard, we are seeking expert advise for resolution of this issue with the latest ppiper/cf-cli.

We would also like to point out here that although we are using latest image of ppiper/jenkins-master for hosting our Jenkins instance, this image (ppiper/jenkins-master) was last updated a year ago in docker hub and there is no subsequent official update since 2022-05-11. Can this be also a potential cause for the compatibility issue?

We really appreciate your help and support in this regard.